# point of intersection of planes

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

We have to find the **point** where the **line** of intersection of planes

$x -2y +z-1 = 0$ and $x+2y -2z-5=0$,

intersects the plane $2x +2y +z+6=0$

I could not get any start how to do it, except for equating the first two planes to determine the line of intersection.

Please help

Comment: Solve the first equation for $y$ and use the result for the second eqatuation.

Comment: $x -2y +z-1 = x+2y -2z-5 \iff 4y-3z-4=0$

Comment: @MrYouMath when we use the result for second equation then there would be two variable

Comment: Yes, and you are looking for a line of intersection ;-).

Comment: Is there is some other method by converting them to symmetrical form @MrYouMath

Comment: koolman: Please be sure to double-check the equations of the two planes which you equated, and the equation of the third plane.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier *without* trying to find the equation of the line !

Indeed, the point is common to the line and the third plane, hence to the three planes, and you just have to solve the $3\times3$ system

$$\begin{cases}x -2y +z-1 &= 0\\
x+2y -2z-5&=0\\
2x +2y +z+6&=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: How can we solve that

Comment: @koolman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation you get:

$$y=1+3/4z$$ plug this into the last equation and solve for $x$:

$$x=-4-5/4z.$$

So the general point is $(x,y,z)=(-4-5/4z,1+3/4z,z)=(-4,1,0)+\frac{1}{4}z(-5,3,4)$ in which $z\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But we should get a single point as the line is intersecting the plane at only one point.

Comment: @koolman You wrote "intersection of planes", which is *always* (in three dimensional space) a straight line, *not* a point...or else the planes are parallel.

Comment: @DonAntonio we have to find the point of intersection of line and the third plane . The line is that line which is formed by intersection of first two planes .

Comment: I think the op means that he's looking for the intersection of the line( $y = \frac 34z +1$ with the plane given by the second equation.  The line $y$ above, I believe, is the intersection of two planes, which were equated in the first equation.

Comment: Then the OP must be crystal clear and write down *that* in his question, lest people will be confused.

Comment: Well, I understood the question, though the op should have specifically listed the two planes $$x -2y +z-1 = 0 = x+2y -2z-5$$.  After equating the two, we see that the intersection (which is a line) is given by $y = \frac 34z +1$.

Comment: Yes you are correct , then how can we solve it

Comment: That's already been said.  You are looking for the point of intersection of three planes, given as three linear equations in x, y, and z.  Solve those three equations.